# Как в тестах Spring Boot расширять контексты

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, юнит-тесты

Вводные данные. Есть абстрактный тестовый класс, в котором загружается контекст приложения, пример:

```
@ContextConfiguration(initializers = AbstractTest.Initializer.class)
@Testcontainers
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles(TEST)
public abstract class AbstractTest
```

В классе *AbstractTest.Initializer* заполняются свойства, вот так:

```
TestPropertyValues.of("foo=bar").applyTo(applicationContext)
```

Я хочу наследоваться в других тестах от этого класса И расширять текущий ApplicationContext другими тестовыми бинами, помеченными @TestComponent, или обычными @Component
В конце должно получиться как-то так:

```
//Необходимые аннотации
class Test extend AbstractTest {
    
    @Autowired
    //тестовый бин, попавший в контекст конкрентно для этого тестового класса
    private SomeTestBean testBean;
}
```

Как это можно провернуть, чтобы контекст из AbstractTest дополнялся бинами из конфигураций дочерних тестовых классов?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@SpringBootTest` по умолчанию сканирует тот же пакет, на классе которого он висит. Я предполагаю, что у тебя есть разделение исходников на основные и тестовые примерно как показано на картинке ниже:

[image: img]

Учитывая вышесказанное, тебе достаточно просто определить свой компонент в том же пакете (или подпакете), где лежит класс с `@SpringBootTest`. При этом этот компонент также должен лежать в `src/test/java`, а не `src/main/java`. Как итого, всё что собирается из `src/test/java` не попадает в итоговый war'ник/jar'ник, а доступно только в процессе исполнения тестов во время сборки .

Comment: Спасибо! Компонент подтянулся в тесте!